# Как убрать обводку в CardView?

Tags: android, android-sdk, material-design, cardview

Делаю CardView. Хочу чтобы карточка была полностью пустой, но почему-то не могу убрать обводку вокруг нее.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_chat_message_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#00000000"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

На рисунке хорошо видно эту обводку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разметка - элемент для ListView?..

Comment: Нет, это RecycleView.

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/chat_rv"
            android:background="#c2fbba" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Вот сюда я все ставляю

Comment: Не надо разметку в комменты - лучше в вопрос. И зачем там столько лишних элементов?.. А активити у вас AppCompatActivity? А в стилях атрибут `background` и `windowBackgound` не переопределены?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрать обводку на CardView не удалось. Нашел другой способ: придется не использовать CardView, а использовать другой контейнер (например LinearLayout) и вставлять его в RecycleView.

Answer (score 1):

Такое отображение вызвано прозрачностью фона для `CardView`. Лечится убиранием прозрачности.

Сделать же прозрачной и без лищних линий не выйдет стандартными средствами. Придётся карточку заменить обычной вьюхой с вручную нарисованной рамкой в качестве фона

Comment: Это так. Только вопрос не в том, как убрать зеленый цвет. А как убрать серую обводку возле CardView. Я пробовал отключить CardView, сделать ее invisible, то обводка пропадает. Следовательно дело в CardView, а не в родителе, который хранит ее.

Comment: @strevg, попробуйте добавить аттрибут `card_view:useCompatPadding="true"` в разметку карточки и/или поиграться с альфа-каналом фона карточки

Comment: Т.е. попробуйте цвет поставить без прозрачности. типа `@android:color/green`

Comment: И непонятно зачем карточка ещё и в Linear засунута

Comment: Поставил цвет карточки, такой же как у фона, без альфа-канала. Обводка пропала. Это решение поможет, когда фон под карточками будет однородный, а что делать когда на фоне будет картинка?

Comment: @strevg, неужели вам надо чтобы карточка прозрачной была?.. Если да, то её, скорее всего, не заставить так работать. Придётся её заменить обычной вьюхой с вручную нарисованной рамкой в качестве фона

Comment: Да, мне нужно сделать карточку прозрачной. Так как внутренности, которые буду туда засовывать будут неправильной формы (облачка для диалогов в чате)

Comment: @strevg, в таком случае да - карточка вам совсем не нужна

Answer (score 1):

Обводка виджета CardView является идеологической для данного виджета. Именно она и отличает его от другого типа виджетов. Но в то же время хорошо вписывается в идеи material design. Если пытаться убрать обводку, то теряется часть идеи заложенной в него. Если же нужна реализация без обводки легче воспользоваться кастоимизируемым под себя ListView.

Comment: ListView меня не устраивает, только тем, что по сравнению с RecycleView для него придется много реализовывать методов и подгонять под Material Design.

Comment: но Вам и CardView не подходит.. В таком случае попробуйте в качестве контейнера использовать RecycleView а в качестве элемента кастомную view

Comment: я так и решил делать)) Предложил такой ответ утром)

Comment: хорошо что пришли к единому варианту))

Answer (score 0):

Убрал, добавив android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@android:color/transparent" в xml разметку для элемента CardView